# How to extract text from a string between where there are multiple entires that meet the criteria and return all values

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

This is an exmaple of the string, and it can be longer

1160752 Meranji Oil Sats -Mt(MA) (000600007056 0001), PE:Toolachee Gas Sats -Mt(MA) (000600007070 0003)GL: Contract Services (510000), COT: Network (N), CO: OM-A00009.0723,Oil Sats -Mt(MA) (000600007053 0003)

The result needs to be column1 600007056 column2 600007070 column3 600007053
I am working in Spotfire and creating calclated columns through transformations as I need the columns to join to other data sets

I have tried the below, but it is only picking up the 1st 600.. number not the others, and there can be an undefined amount of those.

Account is the column with the string

```
Mid([Account],
    Find("(000",[Account]) + Len("(000"),
    Find("0001)",[Account]) - Find("(000",[Account]) - Len("(000"))
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is the structure of the number you need to identify? E.g. always comes after a parenthesis and 3 zeros? Does it always start with 6? Does it have a fixed length?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my guess is correct, and the pattern to look for is:
9 numbers, starting with 6, preceded by 1 opening parenthesis and 3 zeros, followed by a space, 4 numbers and a closing parenthesis

you can grab individual occurrences by:

column1: RXExtract([Amount],'(?<=\\(000)6\\d{8}(?=\\s\\d{4}\\))',1)

column2: RXExtract([Amount],'(?<=\\(000)6\\d{8}(?=\\s\\d{4}\\))',2)

etc.

The tricky bit is to find how many columns to define, as you say there can be many. One way to know would be to first calculate a max number of occurrences like this:

maxn: Max((Len([Amount]) - Len(RXReplace([Amount],'(?<=\\(000)6\\d{8}(?=\\s\\d{4}\\))','','g'))) / 9)

still assuming the number of digits in each column to extract is 9. This compares the length of the original [Amount] to the one with the extracted patterns replaced by an empty string, divided by 9.

Then you know you can define up to maxn columns, the extra ones for the rows with fewer instances will be empty.

Note that Spotfire always wants *two* back-slash for escaping (I had to add more to the editor to make it render correctly, I hope I have not missed any).